# how iterate Hash-Map into another method

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i have this hash map :

```
  HashMap<String, String> meMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        meMap.put(p.getName(), selState);
```

how can i iterate it into another method?How can i pass map to another method to iterate it?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: what is the problem ur facing in iterating?

Comment: i not need iterate hash map when i store key value

Comment: i need iterate it when i click on button

Comment: U can pass hapshmap as a argument in method

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> meMap`

Comment: IDE underline in red (HashMap<String, String>)

Comment: Why don't you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map?answertab=active#tab-top) for how to iterate the Map. To use the map in another method simple pass the Map to the method. Like So `myIteratingMethod(meMAp)` and the function header like so `private void myIteratingMethod(HashMap<> map)`.

Comment: @Abbas your link not help me

Comment: @markella Then perhaps try to be more clear in your question.

Comment: @Abbas my question is clear...

Comment: @markella your question is indeed unclear. Explain what you mean by "your link not help me". What happened? IDE showed a message? NullPointerException? Your problem is different? If it's different, please explain why and how.

Answer (score 0):

`meMap.entrySet()` gives you that ability

You can use it like `for (Entry<String, String> entry : meMap.entrySet()) {...}` or pass to another method

Comment: yes i know, but if i pass to an other method this "HashMap<String, String>" this is underline in red by IDE

Comment: define function parameter Iterable<>

Comment: public void yourFunction(Iterable<> map) {}

Comment: if you want to pass HashMap, then define it like `public void yourFunc(Map<String, String> hashMap) {}`

Comment: Iterabile<> is underline in red

Comment: Red underlin can mean anything, if there is nothing after method declaration (no {}) - this will be underlined. You must learn to read error messages before asking

Comment: public void meMap( Map<String, String> hashMap ) {} this is my function and arguments are underline in red

Comment: @markella you can't make same names for function and variable

Comment: as object of hash map "                            HashMap<String, String> meMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
"

Comment: You just don't know, what you are doing, nobody can help you

Comment: i want pass to another function the hash map...i want iterate it into another function

Comment: You know what mean "iterate"? And red underline can mean about 10 kinds of error - hover mouse over it and read